# How to use binding in the ListBox’s Items to the ViewModel’s properties

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox which displays the collection of MyObjects. The collection is in the ViewModel. I want to handle a click on the button on the ListItem but have some troubles with binding. The binding in the DataTemplate works fine if the property is bound to the MyObject property. But how can I bind it to the property from the ViewModel?

The second question how I can use the information from the item in the code which handles click event. For instance, I want to print out the text from the item’s TextBox.

The code is like that:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Button Content="{Binding .}"
                Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" /> <!--It doesn't work-->
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Objects}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
```

C#:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    VM m_vm;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        m_vm = new VM();
        this.DataContext = m_vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class VM
{
    ObservableCollection<string> _objects;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Objects
    {
      get { return _objects; }
      set { _objects = value; }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        _objects = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Objects.Add("A");
        Objects.Add("B");
        Objects.Add("C");
    }

    //I used relayCommand from the John Smith articles
    RelayCommand _clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_clickCommand == null)
            {
                _clickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.AvatarClick());
            }
            return _clickCommand;
        }
    }

    public void AvatarClick()
    {
        //how to get here the text from the particular item where the button was clicked?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your ListBoxItem's will have the string items from the ObservableCollection Objects as DataContext and from there you don't have any AvatarClick RelayCommand. You can use RelativeSource in the Binding to use the DataContext from the parent ListBox instead.

For your second question, you could make use of the CommandParameter like this

**Xaml**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Button Content="{Binding .}"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickCommand,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public ICommand ClickCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_clickCommand == null)
        {
            _clickCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.AvatarClick(param));
        }
        return _clickCommand;
    }
}

public void AvatarClick(object param)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I have similar problem where I want to toggle the visibility of a dockpanel containing a button&icon inside the listitem based on a bool which is in its vm class. I am not able to fix it based on above ideas. Can I get a specific answer please ??

note: I have two dockpanels inside a list item but i want to toggle visibility of only one dockpanel.